# Object missing from collection after joining?

Tags: scene, collections

So I just joined my character together and it clearly shows on my 3d viewport + when I render an image it shows fine.

However, it literally doesn't show up on my collections tab so I have no idea what happened.

You can see I have it selected, yet nothing shows in my scene collection.

I have no idea how to make it show again???

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hover your mouse over the Outliner and press the Period (.) key on the numpad. That should expand the outliner and hilight your object.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? it shows multiple options yet it's physically not showing under the collections

Comment: You really need to show an image of your whole screen (via the Window > Screenshot menu) and upload the Blend file so that we can see exactly what's going on. At the moment it appears that you have your object selected in the 3D view but the Camera is hilighted in the Outliner.

Comment: I added the full pic, but the camera wasn't selected or else it would've been blue. I only noticed my object disappeared after I tried to join them

Comment: Ok. The Collection icon is hilighted in the outliner and there appears to be at least one more entry out of view at the bottom of the outliner. What happens if you scroll it down with the mouse wheel?

Comment: oh it was hidden in the armature... is that good practice or should I drag it out?

Comment: No. Leave well alone now you've found it! :^)